# How do I configure while loop to use picamera?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So I want to read individual frames of picamera using while loop. Here is what I found for doing it using for loop:

```
 # import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now when I use the above code, I get the video feed but I am planning to do the same using a while loop. Going from the same logic I added a while loop something like this:

```
while True:  frame1=camera.capture_continious(rawCapture,format="bgr",use_video_port=True)
        image1 = frame1.array
        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame1", image1)
        # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

But still I am getting an error as frame1 is a generator and doesn't contain such attributes while the same code is running well with for loop. What modifications can I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function capture_continuous() returns an infinite iterator of images captured continuously from the camera. It does not return a single image. That's is why it does work with a for loop.

In your while loop you should use the capture() function, which does return an image.

You can (and should ;) ) read more about it in this [documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html)